# Convert a Julia DataFrame column with String to one with Int and missing values

Tags: dataframe, julia, missing-data

I need to convert the following `DataFrame`

```
julia> df = DataFrame(:A=>["", "2", "3"], :B=>[1.1, 2.2, 3.3])
```

which looks like

```
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ A      │ B       │
│     │ String │ Float64 │
├─────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │        │ 1.1     │
│ 2   │ 2      │ 2.2     │
│ 3   │ 3      │ 3.3     │
```

I would like to convert A column from `Array{String,1}` to array of `Int` with missing values.

I tried

```
julia> df.A = tryparse.(Int, df.A)
3-element Array{Union{Nothing, Int64},1}:
  nothing
 2
 3

julia> df
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ A      │ B       │
│     │ Union… │ Float64 │
├─────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │        │ 1.1     │
│ 2   │ 2      │ 2.2     │
│ 3   │ 3      │ 3.3     │

julia> eltype(df.A)
Union{Nothing, Int64}
```

but I'm getting A column with elements of type `Union{Nothing, Int64}`.

`nothing` (of type `Nothing`) and `missing` (of type `Missing`) seems to be 2 differents kind of value.

So I wonder how I can A columns with `missing` values instead?

I also wonder if `missing` and `nothing` leads to different performance.

Answer (score 2):

I would have done the following:

```
julia> df.A = map(x->begin val = tryparse(Int, x)
                           ifelse(typeof(val) == Nothing, missing, val)
                      end, df.A)
3-element Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}:
  missing
 2
 3
```

```
julia> df
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ A       │ B       │
│     │ Int64⍰  │ Float64 │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ missing │ 1.1     │
│ 2   │ 2       │ 2.2     │
│ 3   │ 3       │ 3.3     │
```

I think `missing` is more suitable for dataframes which indeed have `missing` values, instead of `nothing`, because the latter is more considered as a `void` in C, or `None` in Python, [see here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/constants/#Core.nothing).

As a side note, `Missing` type has some [Julia functionalities](https://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/man/missing.html).

Comment: Not sure the last code works fine with DataFrame like `df = DataFrame(:A=>["", "2", "3", "-"], :B=>[1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4])` where empty strings should be considered as missing but also strings that can't be parsed as Int (like `-`)

Comment: @scls, yes you're right, that was a too specific code, assuming that missing values are only empty strings, I removed it ;)

Comment: I wonder if a cleanup function shouldn't be defined in DataFrames.jl (or maybe `tryparse` should have an option to ouput `missing` instead of `nothing`

Comment: I found an even easier way of doing: `df.A = replace(df.A, nothing=>missing)`

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `nothing` by `missing` can simply be done using `replace`:

```
julia> df.A = replace(df.A, nothing=>missing)
3-element Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}:
  missing
 2
 3

julia> df
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ A       │ B       │
│     │ Int64⍰  │ Float64 │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ missing │ 1.1     │
│ 2   │ 2       │ 2.2     │
│ 3   │ 3       │ 3.3     │
```

an other solution is to use `tryparsem` function defined as following

```
tryparsem(T, str) = something(tryparse(T, str), missing)
```

and use it like

```
julia> df = DataFrame(:A=>["", "2", "3"], :B=>[1.1, 2.2, 3.3])
julia> df.A = tryparsem.(Int, df.A)
```

Comment: This is a nice way! +1

Comment: See https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/issues/1854 for an ever nicer way.

Comment: This does not work; refer https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/32378